# Chart JS - ocultar legenda

Tags: javascript, chartjs

Olá!

Estou utilizando o Chart.js em um projeto, porém necessito ocultar a legenda que é exibida acima do gráfico.

Alguém que já trabalhou com este gráfico sabe informar como oculto esta parte?

Segue o link do gráfico que estou utilizando:

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-introduction

Segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Muito Bom", "Bom", "Regular", "Ruim", "N/A"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2],
            backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
            'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
            'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
            'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
            'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
            'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)'
            ]
        }]
    },
});
```

Preciso ocultar o label: `label: '# of Votes'`, porém se deixo em branco ou se removo ele fica como undefined.

Comment: Está a falar da tooltip que aparece no mouse hover?

Comment: Estou me referindo a legenda que está escrito: My First Dataset, vou inserir o código na pergunta.

Comment: Consegue colocar o exemplo funcional aqui https://jsfiddle.net/0tfvnmx1/3/ . já importei a biblioteca. Para ver se o consigo ajudar

Comment: Sua resposta está [aqui na documentação](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration)

Comment: Descobri a resposta, inseri no comentário abaixo, encontrei na documentação a opção para desativar a legenda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obtive a resposta, devo inserir a seguinte linha no script:

```
options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }
```

Que ficaria assim:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("campos_um");
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Muito Bom", "Bom", "Regular", "Ruim", "N/A"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2],
            backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
            'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
            'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
            'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
            'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)'
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Pode desativar usando :

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
```

Fonte: [Documentação](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

**Remover a legenda**

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
```

**Remover o Tooltip**

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = false;
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749509/removing-legend-on-charts-with-chart-js-v2